# In which API level android the android:state_selected was introduced

Tags: android

I am using the **android:state_selected** attribute in the following selector :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/verification_calling_device_footer_text_color"/>
    <item android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

I was wondering if **android:state_selected** attribute was introduced in an API level which is more than the one user is having on it android phone. In that case the application will crash.

I coudlnt find the answer to this. Whats the API level in which **android:state_selected** attribute was introduced and how could i avoid the problem of crashing. Will this require any change to AndroidManifest.xml ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html 
`Added in API level 1` (right top corner)

Answer (score 0):

With reference to this [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_selected), state_selected was introduced in `API Level 1` which means it should be available for all versions of android. Thus it should not crash because of this reason.